# Double array with size as user input

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to do something like this

```
int n,m; //or cin>>n>>m;

a[n][m];

//then do whatever with the array
```

The problem is that Visual Studio gives me errors, while dev c++ doesn't. I want to compile it in VS.

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not standard.

Comment: This is called a 2-dimensional array. A double array would be an array of doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the compiler...
Use of `std::vector` is always recommended for such need.
But if you *have to*, then you can allocate that memory on the heap like this...

using `new`(recommended in C++)...

```
cout << "Enter n & m:";
int n, m;
cin >> n >> m;

int** p = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
    p[i] = new int[m];
}
```

or using `malloc` (Do it in C. Not recommended in C++)...

```
cin >> n >> m;

int** p = (int**) malloc (n * (int*));

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p[i] = (int*) malloc(m * (int));
}
```

for a 2D array of `int`s.
But remember to `delete` or `free` it after your use.

Answer (score 2):

Even if your compiler supports VLA(Variable Length Arrays), you didn't declared `a` properly:

```
int a[n][m];
^^^
```

You should use `std::vector` which is a standard way

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > a(n, std::vector<int>(m));
```

Comment: +1 (but remember to change `>>` to `> >` in case you're not using C++1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `std::vector<Type>(n*m)`, that would probably be the nicest way.

If however you want to stay with the array, I guess that it would compile if you allocate the memory on the Heap instead of the stack by calling new/malloc. But remind yourself of freeing the memory afterwards and please check the user input before you do it to prevent malicious inputs.

Answer (score 0):

array needs constant paras.

instaead, you can use `vector< vector <int> >`

Answer (score 0):

[Variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are proposed in the upcoming [C++14 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14), but not yet in the language.

You can however use a `std::vector` of `std::vector` of whatever type you want.

Like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(n, std::vector<int>(m));
```

The above declaration create a vector of vectors of integers, the outer vector of size `n` and the inner vector of size `m`.